# How to get list image url by tapping in gridview item not the index

Tags: flutter, dart

So i have list that has 4 image url
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kob75.jpg)

I want to get the list image url by tapping the item in gridview
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoHqt.jpg)

But when i try using

> productC.productImage.indexOf(item)

i only get the index of the item not the image url

Comment: Well, you already *have* the item (which is the url), so you don't need to look it up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 'item' is your asset imageUrl. Even thought, if you want to get the index and the item, you should take a look at  mapIndexed method from collection library. You can find more info about it [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/mapIndexed.html)

You could use it like this:

```
  final _productImage = [
    'assets/image_helm1.png',
    'assets/image_helm2.png',
    'assets/image_helm3.png',
    'assets/image_helm4.png',
  ];

  _productImage.mapIndexed((index, imageUrl) {
    //..Do something with your index
    //..Do something with your imageUrl
  });
```